# storing a rank in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I am currently trying to store a position rank in a database.

I need to store where a song is ranked by their likes. At the moment I am able to store it like this:

```
SET @r=0;
UPDATE song_board_t SET song_ranking= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY song_likes DESC;
```

This will be something I run on a temporary table each day and then copy into another table.

THe issue I am running into is that I need the song_ranking to be equal if the song_likes are equal for example if two songs have 100 likes each they should both have the same ranking.

At the moment it just counts through the rows so each rank is one more than the previous.

I am ok if some of this needs to maybe be done in PHP rather than sql.

Any help would be appreciated.

THanks in advance

EN

Comment: In oracle this would be a job for the analytic function dense_rank(), but I don't know if mysql has analytic functions. Also I would advise against making the rank persistent. There should be no updates, just selects.

Comment: because of the large amounts of rows i wanted to cron job this everynow and then. A select that then needs to iterate through everything would be quite heavy. Also I would need the persistant values in case a user is viewing a single song and wants to see the ranking. I wouldnt want to have to select all rows just to display the one result. Unless I am thinking about this wrong?

Comment: You are essentially creating a cache for the rankings. Whether or not this pays depends on the number of songs. As long as there are less than 10.000 I wouldn't worry at all using an analytic function (speaking from an oracle perspective). One of the bad thing about persistent ranking is that you cannot easily change to a per-user ranking, ranking during the last year etc. All these simple selects will require to work on the caching mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this query:

```
UPDATE song_board_t s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
    song, /*or whatever the primary key is*/
    @r := IF(@prev = song_likes, @r, @r + 1) as ranking,
    @prev := song_likes
    FROM
    song_board_t
    , (SELECT @r := 0, @prev := null) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY song_likes DESC
) sq ON s.song = sq.song
SET s.song_ranking = sq.ranking;
```